# Rendering partial in Rails - nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial in my rails app.

I have done this successfully with other partials, but the difference between those that worked and this one is that this partial belongs to a nested model. It is nested inside the model's view that I am trying to use to render the partial.

I have two models, Project and Project_question.

Project has many project questions and accepts nested attributes for project question.

Project question belongs to Project.

My routes are:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

My project question controller has:

```
class ProjectQuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /project_questions
  # GET /project_questions.json
  def index
    @project_questions = ProjectQuestion.all
  end

  # GET /project_questions/1
  # GET /project_questions/1.json
  def show


  end

  # GET /project_questions/new
  def new
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    # @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @project_question.project_answers[0] = ProjectAnswer.new

  end

  # GET /project_questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_questions
  # POST /project_questions.json
  def create
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new(project_question_params)
    @project_question.project_id = project_question_params[:project_id]


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(Project.find(project_question_params[:project_id])), notice: 'Project question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_question }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.update(project_question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_question, notice: 'Project question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_questions/1
  # DELETE /project_questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_question
      @project_question = ProjectQuestion.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_question_params
      params[:project_question].permit(:id, :title, :content, :project_id, :user_id,
      project_answer_atttibutes: [:id, :answer, :project_question_id, :user_id]
      )
    end
end
```

My project question form has:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_question] do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :project_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @project.id} %>
          <%= f.input :title, label: 'Question:',  :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Type your question here', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 4, class: 'response-project'} %>
          <%= f.input :content, label: 'Is there any context or other information?', :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Context might help to answer your question', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>

  <br><br><br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send!', :class => "cpb" %>
```

My project question partial has:

```
  </div>
  <div class="generaltext">
    <%= @project.project_question.try(:content) %>
  </div>
```

Inside my project#show, I try to render the protect question partial as follows:

```
<%= render 'project_questions/pqps' %>
```

and the project_questions/_pqps.html.erb file contains:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="categorytitle">
            <%= @project.project_question.title %>

          </div>
          <div class="generaltext">
            <%= @project.project_question.try(:content) %>
          </div>
          <span class="editproject">
            <% if current_user.id == @project.creator_id %>
            <%= link_to 'Answer this question', new_project_question_project_answer_path(:project_quesetion_id => @project_question.id) %>
            <% end %>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error message I get when I try is:

```
undefined method `project_question' for #<Project:0x0000010d8bad40>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Project` model? I think it may be just a typo, like missing a 's' in `@project.project_questions`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the has_many relationship between project and project questions. I had to make a loop to show each question.

This worked for me:

```
<% @project.project_questions.each do |singleQuestion| %>

      <div class="categorytitle">
        <%= singleQuestion.title %>

      </div>
      <div class="generaltext">
        <%= singleQuestion.try(:content) %>
      </div>
```